# How To Make REST Call From Movilizer Movelet

Tags: rest, movilizer

I am new to Movilizer, so pardon me if the question appears silly.

I have created a Movelet and I am using Eclipse with Movilizer Plugin for development. In this Movelet I want to consume an existing REST webservice. The said webservice is presently being consumed by the web based application for which we are developing a Mobile app in Movilizer.

Can someone point the procedure/code snippet to consume a REST service from Movilizer. Please be noted, I need MEL code snippet as I am using Eclipse for development, not SAP system.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have full REST consumer, but it is "just" an HTTP web service, isn't it? You should be able to put it together using network SPI, https://devtools.movilizer.com/confluence/display/DOC25/connect+method with GET/POST

*Example*

```
connID = connect("http://httpstat.us/200", "GET");
if (connID >= 0)
{
    sleep(1000);
    readData = readTextLine(connID);
    close(connID);
}
```

Comment: And you can use MEL to parse JSON string to MEL arrays via: arr jsonToObject(str inputString)

Comment: How to read the result which i am getting from service, right now i am getting readData as 0.

Comment: which is increasing every time to 1,2,3 and then -1.